# How to prove my matrix's powers?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, proof-writing, representation-theory

Being bored I played around with matrices I stumbled upon this matrix.

$$T = \left[\begin{array}{ll|cc}
0&2&0&0\\
\frac{1}{2}&0&0&0\\
\hline 1&0&1&0\\
1&1&0&1
\end{array}\right]$$

What is $T^{2^k}$ for $\cases{k\in \mathbb N\\k>1}$? I have my suspicions what it should be, but how can we **prove** it?

Comment: Is this what you do when you're bored???

Comment: @mathreadler: By induction.

Comment: Out of curiosity, in what context did this matrix come up? And why were you looking to take power of it?

Comment: @KenDuna I have done many questions on matrix representations of various things here on the site - which I got an interest in maybe 3-4 years ago and also some interest in low-level (close to hardware) computational programming. Well I did bsc&msc in EE after all. Multiplication and division by 2 are very practical operations to do in electronics - just a bit shift. Additions are also often fast. And parallell processing of matrix multiplication is nice now when everything is getting more and more cores and more and more focus on parallelism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, let 
$$
T = \begin{pmatrix}A & 0 \\ B & I\end{pmatrix}, \quad A = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 2 \\ \frac{1}{2} & 0\end{pmatrix}, \quad B = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix},
$$
and $I$ is a unit matrix. One may see (by simple induction) that 
$$
T^n = \begin{pmatrix}A^n & 0 \\ B\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}A^i & I\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Also one may note that $A^2 = I$. Thus $A^{2^k} = I$ and
$$
B\sum_{i=0}^{2^k-1}A^i = B\cdot2^{k-1}(A + I) = 2^{k-1}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 \\ \frac{3}{2} & 3\end{pmatrix}.
$$
So the full answer is
$$
T^{2^k} = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 2^{k-1} & 2^k & 1 & 0 \\
3\cdot 2^{k-2} & 3\cdot 2^{k-1} & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Comment: Nice explanation, +1.